# Tensorflow Playground - Explanation of the Feature colored with blue and orange

Tags: tensorflow

[Tensorflow playground](https://playground.tensorflow.org/) input feature $X_1$ is colored orange and blue. What is the meaning of these colors?

I think $(X_1, X_2)$ is training data point representing the coordinates of the dot to classify positive/blue or negative/orange in the OUTPUT on the right.

Then how come a scalar value $X_1$ has orange part and blue part? $X_1$ is not a filter in a CNN, then how come it is half separated blue and half orange with vertical edge in the middle?

Please help understand.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you hover over the features, you can see what they refers to on the image on the right.

Hovering over $X_1$:
[image]

Hovering over $\sin(X_2)$:
[image]

in other words, are represented as binary variables that corresponds on which section the points are located, for example(orange = 0, blue = 1), but might easily be just a visual representation for "positive" (blue) and negative (orange) values, and so the points you can see them as centered in $(0,0)$

Comment: Thanks a lot. "so that the points you can see them as centered in (0,0)" explains it.