# How we can interpret Playground on Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I need to understand how [Playground on Tensorflow](https://playground.tensorflow.org/#activation=relu&regularization=L1&batchSize=10&dataset=xor&regDataset=reg-plane&learningRate=1&regularizationRate=0.01&noise=0&networkShape=2&seed=0.61104&showTestData=false&discretize=false&percTrainData=70&x=true&y=true&xTimesY=true&xSquared=false&ySquared=false&cosX=false&sinX=false&cosY=false&sinY=false&collectStats=false&problem=classification&initZero=false&hideText=false) works.

- How can I interpret `x1, x2, x1^2, x2^2` and... . Because in real neural network, we just have some numbers but, here, how we can interpret the values and colors inside those square boxes? How we should interpret the white line in features?
- How we can interpret the shape of the outputs in each layer?

[image]

Comment: this is part of the answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/582078/tensorflow-playground-explanation-of-the-feature-colored-with-blue-and-orange